# Move Windows to Existing (Non-Blank) Drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, migration

My current setup is an SSD that has Windows installation on it, plus an HDD that holds most of my data.  The HDD has plenty of space on it (more free space than the full size of the SSD).

I'd like to move the entire drive, including the OS (intact) and all the data that's on it to the HDD, so I can re-purpose the SSD for another rig.

I also have an external drive that has roughly enough space to temporarily store the contents of the HDD if that helps.

What's my best option to make this move?  I see a lot of posts on migrating to an SSD or completely new drive, but not onto an existing one.

Comment: Was your Windows installation pre-installed on the system or purchased separately?

Comment: It was pre-installed on the HDD.  I then added the SSD and moved the OS to that.  Now I want to move it back to the HDD.  All of this is on the same PC.

Comment: Sounds good. Two other questions: (1) What did you use to transfer to the SSD the first time.  (2) How much space is used on the SSD and the HD and how much is free on the HD right now?

Comment: On (1) I'm honestly not sure.  I feel like it was something that was built into Windows (or from MS).  I think I used my external drive somehow, but that might have been just a fail-safe/backup that I didn't need to use?  On #2, the SSD has ~150Gb used and the HDD has ~400Gb free.

Comment: How much used on the HDD?

Comment: Actually, my last comment was wrong now that I look at it again.  530GB free of 931GB.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking: Defrag and compress the HDD so that all the data is on (mostly) consecutive sectors.  That will leave you a large empty area on the HDD.  Create a new partition in that area using Windows' Disk Management tools (in Admin Tools).  Then move everything to that partition.  Then use whatever you used to create the SSD to write the primary partition back to the HDD.